# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph'

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I installed networkx by downloading the distribution file and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

It appears to have been successful, I got this message after installing

```
Installed c:\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\decorator-4.0.11-py3.6.egg
Finished processing dependencies for networkx==1.11
```

But when I run a really simple test code, I get errors

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()

print(G.nodes())
print(G.edges())

print(type(G.nodes()))
print(type(G.edges()))
```

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "netExample.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>     G=nx.Graph() 

> AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph'
```

Running `print(dr(nx))` gives the following attributes:

```
> ['GraphMLReader', 'GraphMLWriter', '__builtins__', '__cached__',
> '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__',
> '__path__', '__spec__', 'exception', 'generate_adjlist',
> 'generate_edgelist', 'generate_gexf', 'generate_gml',
> 'generate_graph6', 'generate_graphml', 'generate_multiline_adjlist',
> 'generate_pajek', 'generate_sparse6', 'parse_adjlist',
> 'parse_edgelist', 'parse_gml', 'parse_graph6', 'parse_graphml',
> 'parse_leda', 'parse_multiline_adjlist', 'parse_pajek',
> 'parse_sparse6', 'read_adjlist', 'read_edgelist', 'read_gexf',
> 'read_gml', 'read_gpickle', 'read_graph6', 'read_graphml',
> 'read_leda', 'read_multiline_adjlist', 'read_pajek', 'read_shp',
> 'read_sparse6', 'read_weighted_edgelist', 'read_yaml', 'readwrite',
> 'relabel_gexf_graph', 'utils', 'write_adjlist', 'write_edgelist',
> 'write_gexf', 'write_gml', 'write_gpickle', 'write_graph6',
> 'write_graphml', 'write_multiline_adjlist', 'write_pajek',
> 'write_shp', 'write_sparse6', 'write_weighted_edgelist', 'write_yaml']
```

Comment: check using `pip freeze` whether `networkx` module is successfully installed or not. restart cmd or terminal if required. what is the file name of your script? `networkx.py`? If yes, rename it to some other name, it will work.

Comment: it appears it did, it gives me the text "networkx==1.11"

the file name of my script is "netExamply.py"

Comment: the name of the script is all right (a classic, but not here): `netExample.py` in the stacktrace. Can you do: `print(dir(nx))` to see the available members/objects.

Comment: Graph isn't one of them (full response too long to post in comment). Does that mean a faulty install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the below steps, it worked for me in `python 3.5` version.

1. Downloaded [networkx-1.11.zip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/#downloads)
2. Extracted the zip file
3. open the cmd and `cd to extracted directory`
4. run `python setup.py install`
5. verified the installation using `pip freeze`
6. saved the test code in `netExample.py` file.
7. In CMD, cd to the folder, which contains `netExample.py`
8. run `python netExample.py`

Following is output that I got:

```
D:\Naveen\so>python netExample.py
[]
[]
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

Please check the following:

1. Verify whether you are downloading from the official website.
2. Check if any other file named `networkx.py` is present in Windows Path before the actual `networkx` module is present in

Comment: This is exactly what I did last time, but I think something must have gone wrong during the extraction part. Works like a charm now!