# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'generate_graph6'

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

In my code:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(2, 3),(4, 5), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5), (2, 5), (3, 4)])
nx.generate_graph6(G)
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'generate_graph6'
```

I can't really understand what is this problem. Can I get some help understanding and solving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084985/attributeerror-module-networkx-has-no-attribute-graph)

Comment: @ink I tried some other solutions but non of them worked, I will try also this one but for now I am going to lectures. I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @ink I could't try that solution, but the answer below works perfectly. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frome the `networkx` documentation there is a difference between the versions:

See [documentation of 1.10](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.sparsegraph6.html) and of current [version](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/sparsegraph6.html)

It looks like the [`generate_graph6`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graph6.generate_graph6.html#networkx.readwrite.graph6.generate_graph6) method was removed. 
If you want to know the details, you can take a look at the [commit](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/5c22e401bdf5fdff19147bd1328a934f8d3205b5#diff-702b35c7ef6d54af79be44bd6f64b9e7), which removed `generate_graph6`. Their it states that you can simulate the behaviour of `generate_graph6` with `write_graph6`.

Hope this helps.